# Class instantiation and bound funcitons

Tags: python, class, methods

I'm using a package that defines a class Test with the following snippet of code.

```
if self.accept(proposed_next_state):
    self.state = proposed_next_state
```

and the `__init__` function sets `self.accept` in the following simple way

```
def __init__(self, accept,initial_state):
        self.accept = accept
        self.state = initial_state
```

I'm trying to define a function `func` for `accept` that can use both `proposed_next_state` and `self.state`. The problem is that if I define an instance of the class as

```
instance=Test(func,initial_state)
```

then `func` cannot access `self.state` because it is not bound to `Test`. What's the easiest way to do this?

The workaround I have right now is by extending the class in the following way

```
def extendedTest(Test):
    def func(self, proposed_next_state):
       #do stuff here

instance=extendedTest(func,initial_state)
instance.accept=instance.func
```

but this seems like a hack. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifying attributes of an instance after instantiation does feel a bit hacky. You can override `__init__` instead and make it pass `self.func` as `accept` to the parent method:

```
def extendedTest(Test):
    def __init__(self, initial_state):
        super().__init__(self.func, initial_state)

    def func(self, proposed_next_state):
        #do stuff here

instance = extendedTest(initial_state)
```